# Getting data from a comparison matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a function that returns a comparison matrix from a given list:

```
def compare(a, b):
    if b > a:
        return 1
    elif b < a:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

def matrix(data):
    return [[compare(a, b) for b in data] for a in data]
```

I use this function in this way:

```
>>> matrix([0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3])
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [-1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1],
 [-1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1],
 [-1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0]]
```

I need a function to return data from a given matrix, like the code below, but I don't know how to do.

```
>>> data_from_matrix([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [-1, 0, 1, -1, -1, -1],
                      [-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1],
                      [-1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1],
                      [-1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                      [-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0]])
[0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: So you want to use the information that _all of_ `d1..d5 > d0` to infer that d0 _must be_ zero? Is the original sequence always a permutation of `0..5`, or are there some other constraints you haven't mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple hack would be to compute the sums over every row of the matrix:

```py
def data_from_matrix(m):
    return [(len(m) - 1 - sum(row)) // 2 for row in m]
```

This assumes that the matrix actually defines a total ordering and does not check the consistency of the matrix. Another assumption is that the set the total ordering is supposed to be defined on is `range(len(m))`.

Example:

```py
>>> data_from_matrix([[ 0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
...                   [-1,  0,  1, -1, -1, -1],
...                   [-1, -1,  0, -1, -1, -1],
...                   [-1,  1,  1,  0, -1,  1],
...                   [-1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1],
...                   [-1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  0]])
[0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Nice trick.However, it is going to work only for this specific matrix: [0, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3], b/c comparison matrix does not have sufficient information to restore the original vector.

Comment: @samvel: Of course I assumed that the set the total ordering is defined on is 0, ..., n-1, as I stated in my answer.  This seems to be what the OP wants.